# value not appearing in the rest of my code

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm populating my "filteredLocations" array by using this:

```
    let sampleRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("SamplePost").child("post")

    sampleRef.observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if  let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for child in result{
                let dictionary = child.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let lat = dictionary?["lat"] as! Double
                let long = dictionary?["long"] as! Double
                let structure = MapPoints(Latitude: lat, Longitude: long)
                self.filteredLocations.append(structure)
                print("This is the amount in here \(self.filteredLocations.count)")

            }
        }
    })
```

the print statement within the my snapshot returns 2, but when I print filteredLocations.count anywhere else it returns 0. I have the Firebase code at the start of the viewdidload

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have multiple functions reading from "filteredLocations" that would place points on a map, so I wouldn't be able to use the solution that was used in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that "sampleRef.observeSingleEvent" is asynchronous. What this means is that it is run in a background thread waiting for data while the app continues executing functions like viewWillAppear etc on the main thread.

By the time you get data back from the server the other print count methods would have already been executed before the array was populated with data.

To get a better understanding of this. Place a UIButton on your controller and bind it to a function that prints the array count. Then start the app and press the button. It should print 2 as by the time you press the button you should have got data back from the server.

Comment: Thank you this cleared everything up. Is there anyway I can tell the app to wait until the values are loaded rather than continuing executing the rest of the functions?

Comment: Generally you want to avoid blocking the main thread as this is the thread that controls the UI of the app. If you block this thread then the application will become unresponsive. 

You should let the lifecycle functions like viewDidAppear etc execute. 

If you need to do things after getting the data, then after the "for child in result" is finished executing call the appropriate functions. 

If you're updating the UI from an asynchronous call back, make sure to do it on the main thread, otherwise you won't see the changes immediately.